# Cloud Functions Analytics Event Never Gets Triggered

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-analytics, google-cloud-functions

I have the following [Analytic trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/analytics-events) running on Firebase Functions in my `index.js`:

```js
import functions from "firebase-functions";
import admin from "firebase-admin";

// Do I even need this?
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    privateKey: functions.config().private.key.replace(/\\n/g, "\n"),
    projectId: functions.config().project.id,
    clientEmail: functions.config().client.email,
  }),
});

export const test123 = functions.analytics.event("view_item").onLog((event) => {
  functions.logger.log(`Analytics event fired!`); // This doesn't happen
});
```

(I also have other Firebase Functions like endpoints and CRON jobs that work fine)

But the "Analytics event fired!" doesn't appear in my logs, suggesting the `functions.analytics.event` never gets triggered.

- The event `view_item` is marked as a conversion on Firebase
- The event `view_item` is getting triggered in the Analytics Realtime Overview
- Other functions.analytics.events aren't working either

I can see `test123` when I go to my project on https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/, and clicking "Test function" actually prints "Analytics event fired!" without issue. The `Trigger` is set to "Google Analytics for Firebase (Preview)" (which all seems correct) but it's simply not getting invoked.

Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix this or better debug it?

Edit: I have no explanation, but it started working. Will update post if it stops or if I get more info?

Comment: Have you found the information? or Are you still facing the issue?

Comment: After more investigation, it seems like it just takes a really long time for it to start working, after which changes are reflected instantly

Answer (score 2):

The issue seems to be that it can take up to 12+ hours for any *new* `functions.analytics.event(NEW_EVENT)` to register into the analytics, after which it starts working (and any subsequent changes are as fast as your regular firebase functions deploy).

Also, if the Event is not marked as a Conversion in the `Events` tab of Firebase, it will never fire the trigger.

If you want to test your code before waiting the 12+ hours, test it at https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/ in the meantime.

(If you don't see the function at https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/, it means you didn't set it up properly)